# SharePoint Online Recycle Bin Cleanup PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Working on a PowerShell script to clean out the second stage Recycle Bin in SharePoint Online, but the only Where-Object query examples I can find are for filenames.  Can anyone offer a Where-Object that will filter recycled items by deleted today()-90?

```
 Get-PnPRecycleBinItem -SecondStageOnly | Where-Object LeafName -like "*.docx" | Clear-PnpRecycleBinItem -Force
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeletedDate` and `(Get-Date).AddDays(-90)` should do the trick:

```
Get-PnPRecycleBinItem -SecondStageOnly | 
Where-Object {$_.DeletedDate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) }
```